# How to disable view close option?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I created 2 views. In the *View 1* there is a button *B 1* and upon button click *View 1* gets hidden and *View 2* opens.

But *View 2* shows the close option to the user. I want this close option to be disabled. (The *X* mark at top right of window)

Below is my code snippet:

```java
IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewReference viewToClose = activePage.findViewReference(viewIdToClose);
activePage.hideView(viewToClose);
try {
    activePage.showView(viewIdToOpen);
} catch (PartInitException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I disable the close option in *View 2*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the view using `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point and just set the `closeable` attribute to `false`.

Comment: alexey i am a noob rcp programmer can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use method `addStandaloneView(String viewId, boolean showTitle,
            int relationship, float ratio, String refId)` of class `IPageLayout`. **Be Sure** to make the second argument **showTitle to be false**. Basically, you will call this method in Perspective class like:
`public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {
      public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.addStandaloneView(Contact.ID, false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.3f,
                layout.getEditorArea());
        }
}`